# Making a method template - C++

Tags: c++, templates

Below code is used to get a *std::string* representation from ASCII code.

```
string Helpers::GetStringFromASCII(const int asciiCode) const
{
    return string(1,char(asciiCode));
}
```

It works well. But in my application, I know the ASCII codes at compile time. So I will be calling it like

```
string str =  GetStringFromASCII(175) // I know 175 at compile time
```

Question

Is there any way to make the *GetStringFromASCII* method a template so that the processing happens at compile time and I can avoid calling the function each time at runtime.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what do you really want? a template will buy you zero. you will rather increase your executable size if you're unlucky, and you will not be able to pass runtime values. i would let it as it is

Comment: Beware, ASCII is limited to [0;127], 175 is not an ASCII character.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of template meta programming works well when you're dealing with primitive data types like `int`s and `float`s. If you necessarily need a string object, you can't avoid calling the `std::string` constructor and there's no way that call can happen at compile time. Also, I don't think you can drag the cast to `char` to compile time either, which, in all, means that templates cannot help you here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I got that templates is not needed here.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of feeding an int constant to a string conversion function, use a string constant directly:

> `string str("\xAF"); // 0xAF = 175`

By the way, except for heavy performance needs in a loop, trading code readability for some CPU cycles is rarely money effective overall.

Comment: That looks simple. But as Frederick said, looks like I will not get any benefit here if I use templates.

Comment: Yes you are right, if you really want the performance gain, either use
static const string STRING_175("\xAF");
then reference the const variable, or use
const char* str = "\xAF"
which will be casted to a std::string automatically if necessary

Comment: Actually - this is slower! It needs to do a strlen on "\xAF".

Comment: MSalters, this code allocates from the free store, which will be much slower than doing strlen on a 2-byte string, and may have enough jitter to make the effect of the strlen unmeasurable.

Comment: ...unless the string implementation uses SSO (small string optimization), in which case constructing small strings is essentially free because it doesn't touch the free store, and in which case none of this matters performance-wise.

Comment: Yeah all these optimisations mean nothing beside the string constructor as stated by Frederick. But again, if these cpu cycles are really needed, it would be better to allocate the string out of the loop or statically.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <int asciiCode>
inline string const &getStringFromASCII()
{
  static string s(1,char(asciiCode));
  return s;
}

int main(int, char const**) {
  cout << getStringFromASCII<65>() << endl;
}
```

**EDIT**: returns a ref now

Comment: You get practically zero performance benefit with this.  The 'char' type casting still and happens at run time and so does the string constructor call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why you have used static? What's wrong in just returning the string?

Comment: In your code, I guess getStringFromASCII is not called always. Compiler will create specialization and use that, right?

Comment: Mr Fooz, well if you use static, then also make the function return a reference :) the static is a good idea, but having it still return the string by value will destroy that good idea i think

Comment: @Appu & litb: Thanks for the catch... I forgot to make it return a reference as you suggest.

Comment: Making the string a function-scoped static variable also happens to make this version thread-unsafe: if multiple threads call the function simultaneously the first time it's called, they might initialize the string simultaneously, leaking memory.

Comment: Also, note that declaring the function to be static is unrelated to declaring the variable to be static.

Comment: yeah he should make his function inline instead of static to avoid multiple definitions error. static for functions is deprecated -.-

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even bothering with a helper function?

```
string s( 1, char(175) );
```

That's all you need and it's the quickest you're going to get.